# How to send Mongodb data on request in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Inside of the command line I can display a Mongodb collection with db.collection.find(), but I can't find the equivalent to that for a get request in Node. Here's my Express route:

```
app.get('/latest/imagesearch', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(mLab, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Unable to connect to server", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Connected to server");

        var collection = db.collection('links');

        // res.send(collection.find());

        db.close();
    }
  });
});
```

And the database info:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cf0485a3c6700a3eb8b373"), "term" : "dogs", "when" : 1489962117592 }
```

Comment: What console log statements are printed when you run the express server and go to the localhost:3000/latest/imagesearch url?

Comment: Try: res.send( db.collection('links').find())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the collection object, you can call [collection.find](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find):

```
app.get('/latest/imagesearch', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(mLab, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Unable to connect to server", err);
      return res.send("Unable to connect to server");
    } else {
      console.log("Connected to server");
      var collection = db.collection('links');
      collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
        return res.json(docs);
      });
    }
  });
});
```